# How to use Linq to find the right item in ItemsControl.Items

Tags: linq

I define some ItemsControl and added to the ItemsControl.Items a 12 RadioButtons. 
One of the RadioButton is Checked.
And i want to find the context of the Checked RadioButton.

The code that i wrote ( and does not work well )

```
string str = ( from t1 in itemsControl.Items.OfType<RadioButton>()
               where t1.IsChecked == true
               select t1.Content).ToString();
```

What is my mistake ? 
How can i do it in other way ( i dont want to use for / foreach loop )

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result currently is an `IEnumerable<object>` that has one element (the content of the one checked radio button) - but you just need this one element itself, for that you can use `Single()`:

```
string str = ( from t1 in itemsControl.Items.OfType<RadioButton>()
               where t1.IsChecked
               select t1.Content).Single().ToString();
```

Also `t1.IsChecked` is already boolean, no need to compare it with `true`.